# OpenCL - Releasing platform object

Tags: opencl

I was studying OpenCL releasing functions ( clRelease(objectName) ) and it was interesting for me that there was no function to release Platform (more specifically, cl_platform_id) objects.
Does anybody know the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you create platform objects with a regular `malloc` and not a `clCreateObjectName()` function. So you release them with a regular `free`. I guess it's like that because platforms are host resources.
 Note that it is the same for device objects.

**EDIT:** To clarify a bit, thanks to @chippies' comment: The clGetPlatformIDs() function has two uses. first to query the number of platforms available in the system. Second, **to fill** the memory space you allocated for the platforms with the actual platform(s) you decided to use. You store these platforms in a memory space that you first *malloc*. Therefore when you are done with these platforms you release them with a *free* the memory that you *malloc-ed*.

Comment: clGetPlatformIDs is used to get platform objects, the user does not `malloc` them and should not `free` them either AFAIK.

Comment: You make first a *clGetPlatformIDs()* to query the number of platforms. Then you do something like _platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms*sizeof(cl_platform_id));_ then again a *clGetPlatformIDs()* to **fill** the platforms. But still the object platforms is "created" with a malloc and hence release with a *free*. It's quite different than a *clCreateContext()* for instance that returns right away a context object.